Provider observer shows initialization and updation twice in console for a specific riverpod provider
I am using the ProviderObserver class as per riverpod docs (provider_observer).
A provider fetchProductsProvider is used as below in my code.
    import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart' as prov;
            
    class Schedule extends ConsumerWidget {
         final double parentEdgePadding;
         const ScheduledDelivery({
           super.key,
           required this.parentEdgePadding,
         });
            
         @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
           final productList = ref.watch(fetchProductsProvider(clientUid: null, specificProductId: null));
            
           print('NUM PRODUCTS = ${productList.value?.length}\n');
           return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text('Schedule'),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15.0,
                ),
                prov.Consumer<List<Jobs>?>(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, List<Jobs>? jobs, _) {
                    return switch (productList) {
                      AsyncError(:final error) => Center(child: Text('Error: $error')),
                      AsyncData(:final value) => Builder(
                          builder: (context) {
                          //...
                          final output = manipulate(jobs, value);
                          //...
                          return Text('$output');
                          },
                        ),
                      _ => CircularProgressIndicator()
                    };
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          }

          double manipulate(List<Jobs> jobs, List<Product> products) {
            // do calculations and return a double
          }
      }

This provider is being initialized twice and updated twice when widget is drawn.
Console output:
Provider fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#1d349(null) was initialized with
AsyncLoading<List<Product>>()
NUM PRODUCTS = null

Provider fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#1d349(null) was initialized with
AsyncLoading<List<Product>>()
NUM PRODUCTS = null

Provider fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#1d349(null) updated from
AsyncLoading<List<Product>>() to AsyncData<List<Product>>(value: [Instance of 'Product',
Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product'])
Provider fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#1d349(null) updated from
AsyncLoading<List<Product>>() to AsyncData<List<Product>>(value: [Instance of 'Product',
Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product'])
NUM PRODUCTS = 5

Why is it happening so? and is it causing my firebase reads twice?
The parent widget is a ConsumerStatefulWidget having below snippet of code.
             Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 8.0,
                  ),
                  Schedule(
                    parentEdgePadding: 80.0,
                  ),
                  // .. other children
               ]
             )

